# What is more natural answer?

Tags: american-english

I just got a question from native speaker.
the question is like this.

When did you first driving?

> 1.To get a driver licence at driving school, that is my first driving." 
>  
>   2.The first time I drove was at driving school, to get a driver's license.

What if you have felt #2, I am not familiar at subject sentence as beginner.
so would you please more English? Please don't remove or hide.
if you felt well #1. How can I improve the sentence?

When did you first on trip?

> 3.When I went to Hong Kong at honeymoon, that's my first trip. 
>  4.My first trip was when I went of Hong Kong on my honeymoon.

Also this, please do same above.

Even you can improve 1~4, please let me know your idea.

updated: is this right? 
The first time <(when) I drove> was at [driving school].
(=)
The first time was at driving school.
(+)
I drove for the first time.

Comment: “When did you first driving?” does not sound like something a native speaker would say.

Comment: Thanks but how about this ? When did you first start driving a car?

Comment: That form of the question assumes a continuous period of driving, and asks for its beginning. In that case, I’d probably just report my age (“When I was 16.”). If the person asked “What was the first time you drove?” I’d be more specific.

Comment: Is this right?    The first time <(when) I drove> was at [driving school].

=

The first time was at driving school.

+

I drove for the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence #2 is fine. Here is an alternative.

The first time I drove was at driving school, when I was getting my driver's license.

Comment: Thanks but if you don't mind would you please let me know else options?

Comment: The first time I drove I was 14 years old.
I was 14 years old when I first started driving.
I have been driving for 20 years.
I first time I ever drove was in a field with an old tractor.

Comment: In "the first time when I drove was at driving school", Why it used drove instead drive?

Comment: @user1917217 because it ***was*** for the first time. :)